# Simple CosmosDb query high RU

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am evaluating Cosmos Db for a project and working through the documentation. I have created a sample collection following the documentation on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started. When I run the first query on this page in the local emulator I get the following results:

[image]

Why is the Request Charge 2.89 RUs? From all of the documentation I have read this should be 1 RU. The collection is partitioned on the id field and is auto indexed and Cross Partition Queries are enabled. I have event tried putting both items in the same partition and I get the same results.

Comment: You can also try to pass the partition key so it will limit the query search and lower the RU/s consumition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 RU is the cost of a [Point-Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-a-document) operation, not a query. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/request-units:

> The cost to read a 1 KB item is 1 Request Unit (or 1 RU).

Also there:

> Query patterns: The complexity of a query affects how many RUs are consumed for an operation. Factors that affect the cost of query operations include

If you want to read a single document, and you know the id and partition key, just do a point operation, it will always be cheaper than a query with the `id="something"` query. If you don't know the partition key, then yes, you need a cross partition query, because you don't know on which partition key is stored and there could be multiple documents with the same `id` (as long as their partition keys are different, see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview).

You can use any of the available [SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-v3sdk-samples) or work with the REST API.